# Why selenium webdriver can't find element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, invalidselectorexception

[image]

In screen you can see, that entered selector is only one.

Here is code, where I have entered the same selector, but getting error like this:

```
Element info: {Using=css selector, value=//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]}
Find element :By.cssSelector: //*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]
Get Exception: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Code trils:

```
private static final By naryste = By.cssSelector("//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]");
    @Step("Pasirenkame juridinio asmens organizaciją iš reikšmių sąrašo")
    public createOrganization selectMembership() {
        button.click(naryste);
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator you have used:

```
//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]
```

is essentially an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) but not a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors)

You need to change:

```
By.cssSelector("//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]");
```

As:

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]");
```

Comment: thank you for answer. But selenium can't find this xpath: `Find element :By.xpath: //*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]
Find element :By.xpath: //*[contains(@class,'v-label v-label--active theme--light primary--text') and contains(text(),'Narystė')]`

Comment: @Jetz That should a different error and a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement please.